# Parking lot, combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics

Consider the following situation. There are 8 free spots in the parking lot. The places get occupied by 5 women and 3 men. How many arrangements are possible if 2 women would occupy the first and the last parking lot. Try to explain it with the following solution $5*4*6!$

Answer (score 2):

There are 5 ways to choose a woman for the first spot, and then 4 for the last spot. So we have $5\cdot 4$. Then there are 6 spots and 6 people left over, giving the remaining $6!$ arrangements.